# Search on whole words in AutoCompleteMenu-ScintillaNET on WinForms app

Tags: c#, autocomplete, richtextbox, scintilla

By default, `AutoCompleteMenu-ScintillaNET` searches on the first letter of the words in its list, but I want this search to be on all the letters of the given words, how should I do this? Do I have to change a certain property of it?
[Question link on GitHub](https://github.com/Ahmad45123/AutoCompleteMenu-ScintillaNET/issues/29)